# How to use multiple async / await calls in a string of conditionals?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am using async / await with conditionals:

```
async function validate() {
    const a = await validateA()
    const b = await validateB()
    const c = await validateC()
    return a && b && c ? true : false
}
```

But this does not seem ideal, because there is no reason to execute validateB and validateC if validateA returns false.

I can rewrite it like so:

```
async function validate() {
    const a = await validateA()
    if (!a) return false
    const b = await validateB()
    if (!b) return false
    const c = await validateC()
    return c ? true : false
}
```

But this just looks ugly to me.

Really I would like to do something like this (pseudo-code):

```
async function validate() {
    return await validateA() && await validateB() && await validateC() ? true : false
}
```

This doesn't work of course, but the intent is that, just like an if statement, if a condition fails, subsequent conditions are not evaluated.

How do I write this correctly with async / await?

Comment: `This doesn't work of course` you must've done something wrong, because it actually does work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
async function validate() {
    return await validateA() && await validateB() && await validateC() ? true : false
}
```

> This doesn't work of course, but the intent is that, just like an if
>   statement, if a condition fails, subsequent conditions are not
>   evaluated.

**It works.**

Since `validateX` resolves a boolean value, you can write it like this:

```
return await validateA() && await validateB() && await validateC();
```

```js
const validateA = () => Promise.resolve(true);
const validateB = () => Promise.resolve(true);
const validateC = () => Promise.resolve(false);

async function validate() {
    return await validateA() && await validateB() && await validateC();
}

validate().then(res => console.log(res));
```

---

Another way to achieve that is to reject the promise instead of resolving `false`.

```js
const validateA = () => Promise.resolve();
const validateB = () => Promise.reject(); // Reject if validation fails
const validateC = () => Promise.resolve();


async function validate() {
    try {
    
      await validateA();
      await validateB(); // This will reject
      await validateC(); // This won't run
      return true; // If all validateX were resolved, return true.
      
    } catch(e) {
      return false;
    }
}

validate().then(res => console.log(res));
```

Comment: Neat!  Thanks that's helpful!

Comment: While your second approach works I don't like using try/catch blocks as a control flow mechanism. Just my 2 cents, of course.

Comment: @RenatoGama It's a matter of taste, nevertheless that's why I provided two ways, you can choose the one that suits your style. I like the first approach anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use `async`/`await` directly like that, anywhere an expression can be expected inside an `async` function. Here's an example:

```js
const validateA = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500, true));
const validateB = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500, true));
const validateC = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500, true));
const validateFail = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500, false));

const validate1 = async () => await validateA() && await validateB() && await validateC();
const validate2 = async () => await validateA() && await validateFail() && await validateC();

(async () => {
  console.log('starting');
  const didValidate = await validate1();
  console.log('end, ' + didValidate + ', starting another');
  const didValidate2 = await validate2();
  console.log('end, ' + didValidate2);
})();
```